# Importing Analysis Services 2008 KPI's in a PerformancePoint scorecard

Tags: ssas, performancepoint

I am trying to import a KPI from Analysis Services into a PerformancePoint Scorecard, and when I do, The Dashboard Designer throws an error:

> An unknown error has occurred. If the
>   problem persists contact an
>   administrator. There may be additional
>   information in the server application
>   event log.

When I examine the event log, I find the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Server.ImportExportHelper.GetImportableAsKpis(IBpm pmService, DataSource asDataSource)
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Server.PmServer.GetImportableAsKpis(DataSource dataSource)
```

I have found [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ppsmonitoringandanalytics/thread/433ebc3e-1c6d-4918-acb9-22e4f1ba0a99) which recommends reinstalling Microsoft ADOMD.NET but the installer for that won't run because the server already has a newer version of the product (The server is running SQL Server Analysis Services 2008 which includes Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll version 9.0.3042.0)

Anyone have any ideas (short of finding the DLL myself and manually installing it to the GAC)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the SQLServer2005_ASOLEDB9 file from the [SQL Server 2005 Feature Pack](http://tinyurl.com/r2pw82).  If that's not working for you, you could just grab the DLL off of an existing 2005 installation and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I did install the SQLServer2005_ASOLEDB9 . Still it does not work. My issue is I could not not able to import KPI  from one database . in the same server i can able to import kpi from remaining databases.

Answer (score 0):

http://macraem.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/issues-importing-ssas-2008-kpis-into-performancepoint-2007/

> In .NET we can redirect the assembly bindings in the web.config.  I added the following to the Web.Config file for the PPS Monitoring WebService which Dashboard Designer uses to connect to SSAS:

`<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns=”urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1″>
    <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name=”Microsoft.AnalysisServices” publicKeyToken=”89845dcd8080cc91″ culture=”neutral” />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion=”9.0.242.0″ newVersion=”10.0.0.0″/>

    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>`